# AWSLambda.invoke does not return after the called lambda finished successfully

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have two AWS Lambdas, one is creating individual files and the other is supposed to combine all files in a zip folder. Goal is to create one file per day.
The called Lambda gets the file type as parameter, reads the data from matching DynamoDB and produces the output file.

The calling lambda goes through the list of all file types and for each submits the request to produce a file via the ExecutorService. Its callable does a `AWSLambda.invoke()`.
This works for 29 files but one, always the same and the one that takes the longest with 6 minutes, finished and even 10 minutes later the AWSLambda.invoke() call is still waiting. Eventually the calling lambda dies after 900 seconds (Lambda execution limit).

For example the caller started at 15:50:33, the other lambda was started at 15:50:57, finished at 15:56:47 and the caller kept waiting until 16:03 for it to complete. Meanwhile all other 29 instances were started, completed and their files are ready.

Does anybody have an idea what could be the root cause? How to debug that?

Note: It worked for months, then suddenly I can see that behavior and then it starts to work again after a new code deploy. I am not aware of any changes that should impact that.

The Callable for triggering the child Lambda for a given payload contains that code.

```
InvokeRequest lmbRequest = new InvokeRequest()
     .withFunctionName(functionname)
     .withPayload(inputJSON );
lmbRequest.setInvocationType(InvocationType.RequestResponse);
ClientConfiguration configuration = new ClientConfiguration();
configuration.setSocketTimeout(700000000); // 700 secs max
configuration.setClientExecutionTimeout(700000000);
configuration.setRequestTimeout(700000000);
AWSLambda lambda = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
      .withClientConfiguration(configuration)
      .withRegion(region)
      .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain()).build();
InvokeResult lambdaresult = lambda.invoke(lmbRequest);
String error = lambdaresult.getFunctionError(); 
if (error != null) throw ...;
else return lambdaresult;
```

The log of the called Lambda starts with

```
START RequestId: 34d69efa-a261-40df-a4e7-d4a47bcb5c6c Version: $LATEST
2023-02-24 16:52:37 34d69efa-a261-40df-a4e7-d4a47bcb5c6c INFO File 11 triggered
```

and ends with

```
2023-02-24 16:58:48 34d69efa-a261-40df-a4e7-d4a47bcb5c6c INFO File 11 created
END RequestId: 34d69efa-a261-40df-a4e7-d4a47bcb5c6c
REPORT RequestId: 34d69efa-a261-40df-a4e7-d4a47bcb5c6c
    Duration: 371068.41 ms Billed Duration: 371069 ms
    Memory Size: 4096 MB Max Memory Used: 4096 MB
```

EDIT: The max memory used above worries me. I did not get an exception but there is quite some data in memory. I'll increase the lambda's max memory setting.

Comment: Is SnapStart configured on these Lambda functions? Do CloudWatch Logs for the errant Lambda invocation show START, END, and REPORT logs that are what you expected to see (success and correct, sub-15 minute execution)?

Comment: Snapstart no. START, END, REPORT all present. I will update above post with that info.

Comment: @jarmod You might be on to something: Memory Size: 4096 MB Max Memory Used: 4096 MB

Comment: Yes, that sounds like something to dig into. FYI increasing RAM size for your Lambda functions also proportionally increases CPU, and gives you a greater share of network bandwidth. While it costs more per CPU second, tasks complete faster so the net increase in cost might be quite manageable.